# Proving by induction $P_n : (2n-1)! \leq n^{2n-1}$

Tags: induction

Show by induction that $P_n : (2n-1)! \leq n^{2n-1}$.

My attempt at solution:

$P_n : (2n-1)! \leq n^{2n-1} $.

Check $P_1$: LHS = $1$ and RHS = $1$ $\implies$ $P_1$ is true.

Suppose $P_n$ is true; given that $(2n-1)! \leq n^{2n-1}$, then:

$(2(n+1) - 1)!$

$= (2n+1).(2n).(2n-1)!$

$\leq (2n+1).(2n).n^{2n-1}$

$= 2.(2n+1)n^{2n}$

$\leq 2.(2n+2)n^{2n}$

$= 4.(n+1).n^{2n}$

$\leq 4.(n+1).(n+1)^{2n}$

$ = 4.(n+1)^{2n+1}$

$ \leq 4.(n+1)^{2(n+1)-1}$

This is not quite $P_{n+1}$. Can anyone do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\ge 2$ for all $n\ge 1$.

You correctly obtained $4(n+1)n^{2n}$ and you need to show this is less than $(n+1)^{2n+1}$.

$$(n+1)^{2n+1}=(n+1)n^{2n}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2n}$$

Over to you!

Comment: The fact that $\left (1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \geq 2$ for all $n \geq 1$ is more directly applicable. Maybe it's obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - well spotted.